# Verificar si un valor existe en el arreglo y si es el ultimo del mismo tipo

Tags: javascript

Hola comunidad me entro una duda ya que estoy manejando usuarios por rol y quería validar que el ultimo 'Administrador' NO se pueda desactivar.

Entonces tengo un arreglo de usuario con sus Roles:

```
  const usuarios = [
    { id: 1, name: "John", role: "Administrador" },
    { id: 2, name: " Alex", role: "Usuario" },
    { id: 3, name: "Larry", role: "Administrador" },
    { id: 4, name: "Bob", role: "Usuario" },
    { id: 5, name: "Rick", role: "Usuario" },
  ];
```

Quiero verificar que exista el rol 'Administrador' y que si es el ultimo me aparezca la alerta en este caso si yo elimino de mi CRUD al usuario con id = 3 y en caso de que me quede solo el usuario con id = 1 me salga el error al intentar desactivarlo.

La finalidad de esto es que exista un usuario 'Administrador' y que el ultimo no se pueda desactivar.

Comment: Eso suena más a una validación que debería hacerse en el backend.

Comment: Listo si solo quería saber la lógica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podrias usar un filtro en el array para comprobar cuantos administradores hay antes de intentar borrar alguno.

aqui un ejemplo sencillo:

```
var adminUsers = usuarios.filter((usuario)=>{ //aplicamos el filtro y usamos cada elemento del array(usuario)
  if(usuario.role === 'Administrador'){ //le decimos al filtro que compruebe si el rol es Administrador
     return true;  //si se cumple, lo agrega al nuevo array filtrado
  }else{
     return false; //si no se cumple, no lo agrega
  }
});

if(adminUsers.length >=2){ //comprobamos que hay mas de un administrador
   //borramos o modificamos el usuario que sea...
}else{
   //no se puede eliminar el ultimo admin...
}
```

pero, efectivamente, coincido con lo que te indican en los comentarios, espero que esto vaya en un backend

Comment: Listo gracias lo tendré en cuenta.

Comment: por favor, valora la respuesta si te ha parecido util, saludos.